# Android Firebase: Manually update local cache

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Chat app with groups and each group show what was the last message.
When we open the app and we have unread chats. the most recent message is taking too long to show (like 2s~3s).

This is because i am using **setPersistenceEnabled(true)** so firebase send first a query to the local cache and then to the server.

I am trying to fix this lag.

**What i think we can do:**

While the app is in background, every time we:

1- We receive a push notification about a new message in a group.

2- We open the local FirebaseDatabase where the cache is stored and make the update so we keep this information always fresh.

It will not bring bad consequences when the app sync with the server?
There is another way to fix this problem?

Comment: There is no public API to update Firebase's disk cache. It sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you show the minimal code that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Thank u so much Frank for comment, i find a way to fixed.. thanks

Comment: @MarioEnriqueGonzalezHernand If you found a way to fix the problem; it's considered common courtesy to answer your own question, as to help others who might be experiencing a common problem.

Comment: So what was you solution? I have exactly same issue